# В чем отличие ассоциативных списков от отображения, в Haskell?

Tags: list, список, терминология, структуры-данных, haskell

Что такое отображение в языке Hakell, и чем оно отличается от ассоциативных списков?

Comment: Термин "отображение" мне ничего не говорит. Как это выглядит по-английски?

Comment: Наткнулся на этот термин в книге Learn You a Haskell for Great Good: http://learnyouahaskell.com/modules#data-map В оригинале видимо будет просто "map".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Data.Map.Map` (по вашей ссылке) - это структура данных, логически представляющая собой множество пар "ключ"/"значение". Например меню: Котлеты => 3р, Суп => 5р, Компот => 1р. Ключи уникальные (т.е. не может быть два разных значения к одному и тому же ключу).

Такая структура данных по-русски обычно называется "*словарь*". Но можно в принципе её интерпретировать как *отображение* множества ключей на множество значений. Видимо поэтому в переводе использовано именно это слово.

Реализация такой структуры данных может варьироваться от списка пар (он же "ассоциативный список") до B-деревьев. Конкретная библиотека `Data.Map` в Haskell, [согласно документации](https://www.stackage.org/haddock/lts-14.6/containers-0.6.0.1/Data-Map.html), реализована на основе двоичных сбалансированных деревьев.

Отличие этой конкретной библиотеки `Data.Map` от ассоциативных списков, в общем-то, в том и состоит: другая внутренняя реализация. Для пользователя это отличие выражается в скорости: например, поиск а ассоциативном списке имеет сложность O(N), а в двоичном дереве - O(log N).